# How to store zip file artifact in azure artifact feed

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-artifacts

I have published an artifact which is a zip file in a pipeline build. Now I want to push this in azure artifact? How can I modify my pipeline to store in artifact feed

Comment: You have already stored it? If so then after creating the zip file, use the Copy Files task to copy the zip file to a target folder, and then use the Publish Build Artifacts task to publish the zip file to your Azure Artifacts feed.

Comment: @Arko Thanks for the reply, can u please elaborate what steps i need to take to  publish the zip file to Azure Artifacts feed

Comment: @kiranitagi, I have updated my answer below with more details about how to configure the permissions of build identities so that you can publish packages to Azure Artifacts feed in pipeline (see **EDIT**).

Answer (score 1):

You can publish the ZIP file as a [universal package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/quickstarts/universal-packages?view=azure-devops&tabs=Windows) in Azure Artifacts feed using the [**UniversalPackages**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/universal-packages-v0?view=azure-pipelines) task.

```yaml
variables:
  package_version: 1.0.0

steps:
. . .

- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Publish Universal Package'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishDirectory: 'path/to/file.zip'  # Path to the ZIP file.
    vstsFeedPublish: '{feed name}'  # Specifies the FeedName for an organization-scoped feed, projectName/FeedName or ProjectID/FeedID for a project-scoped feed. 
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: '{package name}'  # The name cannot contains uppercase.
    versionOption: custom
    versionPublish: '$(package_version)'  # Specify the version number of the universal package.
    packagePublishDescription: 'My Universal package.'
```

Normally, you can publish almost any type files as universal packages in Azure Artifacts.

---

**EDIT:**

When publishing packages to Azure Artifacts feed in pipeline, you also need to go to the **Feed Settings** > **Permissions** page to check and ensure the following build identities has been assigned with the **`Contributor`** role at least:

- **Project Collection Build Service ({Organization Name})**
- **{Project Name} Build Service ({Organization Name})**

[image]

For more details, you can reference the documentation "[**Job access tokens**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)".

---